# Function composition (non-measurable Lebesgue)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f(x)$ a function which is non-measurable Lebesgue, then ¿$e^{f(x)}$ is non-measurable Lebesgue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

If not then also $f(x)=\ln e^{f(x)}$ would be Lebesgue-measurable.

Comment: I thought that, but I wasn't sure. Thanks a lot!